# How can I compress byte Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image, byte

I have an Image which getting grom user Gallery and I convert this image to Byte Array like

```
   let imageOther = myImage
    let dataOther = imageOther.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
```

This `dataOther` type is `Data` and about 700k KB. I know If I change `jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)` this , I can reduce this size but If I change this , MyImage quality is also down. So I want to compress this byteArray to reduce size and send to server with no losing quality. I searched some questions and answers in SO but can't find anything.

So , How can I compress byte Array for Image with no losing quality of image?

Comment: You can send it as HEIC instead of jpeg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830224/how-can-i-convert-from-uiimage-to-heif-heic-data-in-swift/61830766#61830766