# Value of type UIImage has no member cgImageOrientation

Tags: swift, ios14, xcode12, coreml, apple-vision

I am new coreml and I was reading a book I came across a code snippet and when I tried to run it I got the above error , I Googled but got no luck ,
here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Vision
extension UIImage {
    func detectFaces(completion:@escaping ([VNFaceObservation]?)->()){
        guard let image = self.cgImage else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: self.cgImageOrientation)
            //above error here I think cgImageOrientation is no longer available but what's the solution anyways
        }
    }
}
```

here I am using swiftUI and lifecycle methods are also selected as swiftui
,
The book name is "Practical Artificial intelligence with swift" by orielly
[image: code from the book page 1]

[image: page 2]

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post the title and author of the book, and where in the book you found this code.

Comment: I have edited the post and mentioned the name of book also mentioned the photos @robmayoff

Comment: Yes but that same tutorial also tells you how to declare cgImageOrientation. You did not follow directions.

Comment: I have read those page twice now but can you tell me where it is , @matt thank you

Comment: It's in a later part. It's step 8 of creating `Views.swift`.

Comment: ooh got it , thank you @robmayoff , I didn't went that further reading because I was stuck in the first place , thank you though

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar https://stackoverflow.com/a/61830766/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to continue working through the tutorial before you'll be able to compile it. The next section of the book talks about creating `Views.swift`, and step 8 of that section includes this extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    func fixOrientation() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
        self.draw(at: .zero)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }

    var cgImageOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation {
        switch self.imageOrientation {
            case .up: return .up
            case .down: return .down
            case .left: return .left
            case .right: return .right
            case .upMirrored: return .upMirrored
            case .downMirrored: return .downMirrored
            case .leftMirrored: return .leftMirrored
            case .rightMirrored: return .rightMirrored
        }
    }
}
```